# PSQL get other children given a partial group of children

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of objects, a table of groups of objects, and a table to link the two.
So given some group of children (these will be searched by object position within a viewed box on a pam but I'm simplifying here), I need to get all of the possible objects of the groups the objects are in. This is shallow there's no deeper comparison needed.

```
objects_table
id | name
=========
1  | foo
2  | bar
3  | baz
4  | qux
```

```
groups_table
id | name
=========
1  | group_1
2  | group_2
3  | group_3
```

```
objects_groups_table
group_id | object_id
==============
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 2
2        | 4
3        | 1
3        | 3
```

This is what I've been doing so far:

```
select o2.id
from objects o
join objects_groups_table ogt on o.id = ogt.object_id
join objects_groups_table ogt2 on ogt2.group_id= ogt.group_id
join objects o2 on ogt2.object_id = o.id
where o.name in ('bar', 'qux')
```

Which does successfully give me 1, 2, and 4. However I keep thinking there is a better way to do this but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Your method is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiple joins I supplied seems to be the way to do this kind of thing.